# zend form client side validation

Tags: forms, validation, zend-framework

I am trying to validate a form created by zend form library. It is validating the form properly, but when I press tab button then its validating all the fields immediately. But it should be validating after press the tab button or press the final submit button. 
My code is like:

```
$this->addElement('text', 'email', array(
        'label' => 'Email:',
        'required' => true,
        'class' => 'span12',
        'attribs' => array(
            'required' => true,
            'pattern'=> "^[A-Za-z0-9._]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$"
        )
    ));

$this->addElement('text', 'name', array(
        'label' => 'Name:',
        'required' => true,
        'class' => 'span12',
        'attribs' => array(
            'required' => true,
            'pattern' => '[a-zA-Z]{4,}'
        )
  ));
$this->addElement('text', 'phone', array(
        'label' => 'Phone:',
        'required' => true,
        'class' => 'span12',
        'attribs' => array(
            'required' => true,
            'pattern' => '\d{4,}'
        )
  ));
```

Please find the image.
[image]
Pressing tab after writing email address, showing red box for name and phone number.

Comment: anybody is there to help me regarding this issue?

Comment: in which browser? This is browser issue, not a problem in framework

Comment: I am opening in mozilla firefox(v-23)